# Hover-эффект в навигации bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Не могу найти, где задается hover-эффект для элементов навигации. При наведении на элемент меню появляется белый бэкграунд (см. рисунок). Я в css его нигде не прописывал, через firebug тоже не обнаруживается, применяется именно к li.
Искал в bootstrap.js - безрезультатно. Прошу помощи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<nav class="mainMenu"><a class="hamburger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="menu">
          <li class="menuItem animated fadeInRight fadeLeftOut" style="opacity: 1;"><a class="menuLink" href="" title="">главная</a></li>
          <li class="menuItem animated fadeInRight fadeLeftOut" style="opacity: 1;"><a class="menuLink" href="" title="">о проекте</a></li>
          <li class="menuItem animated fadeInRight fadeLeftOut" style="opacity: 1;"><a class="menuLink" href="" title="">контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Скрин]

Не там и не то искали

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! очень помогли мне

Answer (score 2):

Бэкграунд серый, а не белый. Применяется не к `li`, а к `a`.
Через диспетчер вполне должен детектиться. Вероятно, не там искался.
Тянутся стили из `bootstrap.css`:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что нужно